# Kivy app crashes saying no module name "chardet"

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer, python-for-android

While building kivy app for android using buildozer, I found an error saying pdfminer module was not found. Then I included the requirements of pdfplumber in the buildozer.spec file. Then I got the error that chardet was not found. Now should I keep finding and adding the requirements of the other modules as well? That is a very difficult process. Is there any easy solution for this? Please help. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

> Now should I keep finding and adding the requirements of the other modules as well?

Yes, you should.

> Is there any easy solution for this?

You could make a virtualenv, install what you need letting pip resolve dependencies, then export the installed packages list and use that in buildozer.

Comment: That seems a great solution. I will try it. Well do you mean to use all the installed dependencies as directories imported by the main.py or to just add the requirements name